# How to get the collection of Excel Sheet's first rows column data (using C#)

Tags: c#, excel

i have an Excel sheet with (for example) 5 columns and 15 rows. all these columns and rows are filled with some data.Now i want to get all the 5 columns data in the 1st row of my Excel sheet, So that i can iterate through each one of them and display on my UI . 
How to get it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of Excel files you need to read from? xls, xlsx?

Comment: Luckily if he decides to go with one of the answers provided it won't matter. There are ADO.NET connection string available for both connection types.

Comment: Please remember to mark the most appropriate response as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use C# Excel Interop.

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel class gives you enough flexibility to load and do anything with the data.

refer http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel

Answer (score 0):

One very simple option is using the Excel spreadsheet as an OLE DB data source. You can find the connection strings at:

Excel (.xls): http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

Excel 2007 (.xslx): http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007

Comment: due to some reason am not using OLE DB.So, if there is any alternative, plz let me know

Comment: Refer to Robotik's answer. Koogra appears to be a good free solution: http://sourceforge.net/projects/koogra/. Otherwise you can use COM interop of the native COM libraries provided by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Your can read Excel as a  oledb datasource. 
The First Row is title, your may get it form Datatable or Datareader. The rest rows is data in or  Datatable or Datareader.